# Организация хранения изображений на сервере?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Думаю над организацией хранения изображений на сервере. Почитал в интернете, решил создать таблицу с параметрами и папку с изображениями.

Таблица получается такого вида:

| id | name | key_words | file_extension | file_path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Вот только задумался над колонкой **key_words** - ключевые слова. Можно, конечно сделать его текстовым и делать выборка на содержание подстроки в строке - правильно ли это? Или есть более оптимальный способ организации данных?

Дополнение:

Есть ли смыл создавать таблицы по ключевым словам?

Тогда  **key_words** можно будет убрать из таблицы, а в таблицах ключевых слов указывать **ID** из таблицы файлов.

Будет ли такой способ есть ресурсы сервера или лучше использовать 1ый вариант?

Comment: *Можно, конечно сделать его текстовым и делать выборка на содержание подстроки в строке - правильно ли это?* Нет. Читать по типу связи много-ко-много.

Comment: Делать текстом не стоит. А как стоит зависит от требований, можно через many-to-many, а можно сделать поле массивом. Главные вопросы про жизненный цикл ключевых слов. Существует ти возможность редактировать список ключевых слов сам по себе в отрыве от файлов? Или ключевые слова задаются при создании/редактированнии файла и при этом можно задавать новые?

Comment: Я решил сделать 2 таблицы отношением 1:M (файлы : ключевые слова). Думаю так правильнее будет

Comment: сами файлы хранятся в директории под уникальным индексом из таблицы файлы